# HTML form to choose file only eBooks? {file-type}

Tags: html, forms, select, upload, file-type

I want to create a form using an upload "choose file" option. I would like to limit the files that display to show only .epub files and .mobi when the selecting pop up box on the OS opens. **It should display only those type of files.**

I got it to work with only images and only audio using the code below but **how would I get the select pop up box to only display these two types of ebooks, .mobi and .epub?**

**Below is the image and audio code that works just fine.**

Displays Image only files:

```
<input id="ImageuploadBtn" type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="upload" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg"/>
```

Displays Audio only files:

```
<input id="Mp3uploadBtn" type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="upload" accept="audio/mp3, audio/wav"/>
```

I believe it would be something like accept="ebook/epub" etc... but that does not work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Those are MIME types, so I'd look up e.g. `.epub mime type` (it seems to be `application/epub+zip`). It's possible that not all browser/OS combinations are able to correctly identify those - you'd have to try out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input id="EbookuploadBtn" type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="upload" accept=".epub, .mobi"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the dot. :)